# FORTRAN 77 comments starting at column 7

Tags: fortran, comments, fortran77

If I understand correctly, any line that starts with `C` in column 1 is automatically a comment. So why do some code samples I see start the comment text at column 7? Is this just to make all text line up a little nicer, or was it required by some compilers?

Comment: You should really show some example of such code. Please note that Fortran 77 has been dead for decades and compilers now distinguish the fixed source form and the free source form of some more recent standard revisions. They typically have different file extensions (fixed: .f, .for; free: .f90)

Comment: Provided the C is in column one, it does not matter where the comment text is. Are you just asking about this? Where is the C characters in the coments you are asking about?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Yes. For example the code here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4939/z40007332024/index.html `c      Start expression analyzer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where the text of the comments start is completely irrelevant to the compiler, the compiler just ignores the line or the punch card.

It is just up to the programmer to format the comments based on the reasons that made him/her to create such comment. Often, programmers will want the comments to be somehow aligned, but it is not necessary.

For example, if a line of code that contained a numeric label is commented out, it will often start earlier than column 7.

Comment: Agreed.  I was a FORTRAN programmer way back when, and I did see a fair number of comments starting at column 7. But I didn't like that; it made it more difficult to distinguish comments from code. (This was before syntax highlighting.) So I typically started comments in column 4 or 5. See http://60bits.net/msu/mycomp/bench.htm